# How to know when the Recyler view in android is done inflating items?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, pagination

The requirement is that I want to highlight the first item of recycler view on my screen. I am using recyclerView.getChildAt(0) to get the first item but how do I figure out whether the first item of recycler view is available or not? I can't directly call getChildAt() because in some cases the network response might be slow and getChildAt(0) may return null.

Tried using onGlobalLayoutListener, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not highlight it in `onBindViewHolder` of the adapter? You can check if the item is at position 0 or not and highlight accordingly. The adapter is responsible for the views anyway. You don't need to handle it outside the adapter class.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: YourHolderType, position: Int) {
    //...

    if (position == 0) {
        // highlight the view in the holder
    } else {
        // de-highlight the view
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this approach will also have problems in an app that uses `notifyItemInserted()` (or `DiffUtil` or `ListAdapter`) since the item originally bound to position 0 won't have `onBindViewHolder` called if a new first item is inserted.

Comment: @BenP. Good point. This is limited in usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

To find count of total items (instead of child-views), check like:

```java
if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() > 0) {
    // Do something with items...
} else {
    // No items, do something else?
}
```

### Listener style

In case you are not sure when to do above check:

```java
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;

// ...

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false){
    @Override
    public void onLayoutCompleted(RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.onLayoutCompleted(state);

        // Your check should be here...
    }
);
```